# Is there any reason the PHP ssh2_scp_send() function will not work on the same machine?

Tags: php

I am trying to connect via ssh from php, and send a file. When the machines are different, it works. When I connect to the same machine, it doesn't work.

```
$this->conn = ssh2_connect($this->ci['host'],$this->ci['ssh_port']);
ssh2_scp_send($this->conn,$ssh_source,$ssh_destination);
```

The connection $this->conn is valid in both cases.
So is there any reasons why ssh2_scp_send() will not work when $this->conn connects to the same machine? When trying on the same machine I get: Warning: ssh2_scp_send(): Failure creating remote file: (null)

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php)

[1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php): http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-scp-send.php Documentation this function is use for Copy a file from the local filesystem to the remote server using the SCP protocol.

So for same system you can use this function - [copy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php)

Comment: Yes I know, it's just that I would prefer not to modify the code and add a bunch of IFs. I was expecting that - if the ssh2_connect() is working to the same machine - ssh2_scp_send() would also work... the documentation doesn't say there is any restriction in this regard.